# Please Can Anyone help Me to drive the equation for Electric Field Around a test Charge Around A uniform Ring.

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields

Please can i get a mathematical relation for electric Field around a test Charge Lying in the region of influence around a uniformly Distributed Charged Ring .